# Using part of enum for internal usage?

Tags: c#, enums

I wanted to know what is a good option to solve this issue ,
I have a class that expose an enum : (this is just an example)

```
public class Foo
{
    public State FooState { get; private set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }

    public Foo(State state)
    {
        FooState = state;
    }

    public Foo()
    {           
    }

    public enum State
    {
        None,
        Bad,
        Good
    }
}
```

in one use of the class the user can adjust the state, and on the other he can't so the state is set on NONE and that good but i dont want the user to have the possibility of setting it to None. i Know that there isnt an internal enum field obviously, is there any way it can be done else, bare in mine that the Foo class cant be changed due to specification.

**Clarification**
The meaning of the class can not be change is that the design and purpose of the class can not change, not the class itself.

The state of the class is only in use when the c'tor get a value. i cant use two classes or use interface due to reflection use in the future. (i just cant use typeof)

Comment: So you want to change the behaviour of the Foo class, but you can't change it? Um... please clarify.

Comment: "bare in mine that the Foo class cant be changed due to specification. " Can you change the implementation of the Foo class, like throw an exception in the constructor?

Comment: where is the state set? prohibit setting it to `None`.

Comment: Can you change nothing in the `Foo` class, since `State` is in `Foo` it would seem you can't change anything.

Comment: I don't get it (I think)... Why can't your empty Foo constructor just set FooState = State.None and not give the user an opportunity to change it?

Comment: How would the class know whether it is being used in the "settable" use case or the "unsettable" use case.  When you say "can't be changed" do you mean you can't change the signature of the public members because if you can't changes it's internal logic then you are pretty screwed.

Comment: I'd make the setter validate the value. But if you can't change anything in `Foo` you're pretty much out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this by providing two interfaces with different access level, implement them explicitly and instead of `Foo` type use one of the interfaces either for read-only or full access.

Since `Foo` can not be changed you can use Wrapper approach:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(State.Good);
FooWrapper fooWrapper = new FooWrapper(foo);

// would be read-write
(FooWrapper as IReaonlyState).State

// would be readonly
(FooWrapper as IWritableState).State


public interface IReadonlyState
{
    State FooState { get; }
}

public interface IWritableState
{
    State FooState { get; set; }
}

public class FooWrapper : IReadonlyState, IWritableState
{
    Foo foo;

    public FooWrapper(Foo foo)
    { 
       this.foo = foo;
    }

   State IReadonlyState.FooState
   {
      get
      {
         return this.foo.FooState;
      }
   }

   State IWritableState.FooState
   {
      get
      {
         return this.foo.FooState;
      }

      set
      {
         this.foo.FooState = value;
      }
   }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the consumer to be able to set both State=Bad and State=Good. 
But if State==None you should be able to read, but not change it. Sounds like you need to implement the setter explicitly.

Comment: Did you try to implement the setter explicitly so that you can check existing state before allowing the change?